# How do I change the server port and launch a grails application during a functional test?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, functional-testing, geb

According to [the documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.5/guide/single.html#functionalTesting), a grails application will only launch if `baseURL` is not set or if `-inline` is set (ignore `-war`). However, if I specify `grails.server.port.http` either on the command line with `-D` or in `BuildConfig.groovy`, the grails application (unexpectedly) doesn't launch, even if I add `-inline`, e.g.:

```
grails test-app functional: -inline -Dgrails.server.port.http=8090
```

if I set `baseURL` to port 8090 (i.e., instead of trying `grails.server.port.http`) the grails application launches on 8080.

I'm using grails 2.5.5 on macOS 10.12.6.

Should this work and I'm missing some documentation somewhere?

Comment: Just using `-Dserver.port=8090` should do the trick.

Comment: That seems to work the same as `grails.server.port.http` -- the grails application isn't launching and it jumps straight into the functional tests.